# Average of list of unequal length in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, mean

I have list of vectors of unequal lengths. What I want is the avg. at each index. For example:

```
a = c(2,3,4)
b = c(2,3,4,5) 
c = c(5,0,3,4,6)

avg(a,b,c) = c(9/3, 6/3, 11/3, 9/2, 6/1)
```

How to achieve this in R ?

Answer (score 7):

We can place the vectors in a `list`, pad NA for list elements that have less number of element and do the `rowMeans`

```
lst <- list(a, b, c)
rowMeans(sapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))), na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 3.000000 2.000000 3.666667 4.500000 6.000000
```

#### data

```
a <- 2:4
b <- 2:5
c <- c(5, 0, 3, 4, 6)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cbind.fill` function in `rowr` package

`cbind` the data with `fill` option as `NA` and apply `colMeans` on the `t`ranspose of the data.frame

```
library(rowr)
colMeans(t(cbind.fill(a, b, c, fill = NA)), na.rm = T)

#[1] 3.000000 2.000000 3.666667 4.500000 6.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this using base R:

```
ls <- list(a, b, c)
sapply(1:max(lengths(ls)), function(i) mean(sapply(ls, function(x) x[i]), na.rm = T))

# [1] 3.000000 2.000000 3.666667 4.500000 6.000000
```

The idea is to apply the `mean` function on `ls` (on the `1th, 2th, 3th, ...` of each vector in list) and ignoring `NA` values.