# Clustering values with given threshold

Tags: r, vector, grouping, cluster-analysis

I have several vectors:

```
a <- c(1.1, 2.9, 3.9, 5.2)
b <- c(1.0, 1.9, 4.0, 5.1)
c <- c(0.9, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.0, 11.13)
```

They can have different length.

I want to combine them in such a way to obtain a general vector with averaged values if there are similar meanings in all of the vectors or in any pairs of them; and with an initial meanings if this meaning is only in one vector. For averaging I would like to use a threshold = 0.2.

My explanation could be a bit confusing, but here is the general vector I want to obtain:

```
d <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5.1, 11.13)
```

I have around 12 vectors and about 2000 values in each vector.

I will be glad for any help

Comment: Can you explain how are you getting 1, 2, 3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Average of list of unequal length in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569378/average-of-list-of-unequal-length-in-r)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `5.1` rather than `5`?

Comment: a[1] = 1.1
b[1] = 1.0
c[1] = 0.9
Average = 1

a[2] = 2.9 - this meaning differ from average of other vectors more than 0.2 (threshold)
b[2] = 1.9
c[c] = 2.1
Average for a and b = 2

a[2] = 2.9 (It is compared again as at previous step it wasn't somehow located into general vector)
b[3] = 4.0 (the same story as for a[3] at previous step)
c[3] = 3.1
Average for a and c = 3

a[6] = NA
b[6] = NA
c[6] = 11.13
 so d[6] = 11.13

Comment: oh, sorry, it really should be 5.1

Comment: That task is similar but meaning are averaged because their index. In my case, similar meaning can stay at different index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a clustering problem (clustered by distance). You can try the code below

```
library(igraph)

v <- sort(c(a, b, c))

tapply(
    v,
    membership(components(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(dist(v)) <= 0.2 + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)))),
    mean
)
```

which gives

```
    1     2     3     4     5     6
 1.00  2.00  3.00  4.00  5.10 11.13
```